# How can I pass values in a custom URL?

Tags: 2013, custom-url

I have 3 fields in a schema. To one of the fields I added a custom URL. The custom URL points to a .NET page which I have created. While creating the component, when I click on the custom URL field I need to pass the field value of 2 other fields to that custom URL page.

I have 3 fields like below.

1. Video Name
2. Short Desc.
3. Video ID

Video ID has custom URl(MY .NET Page). I need to pass video name and Short Desc pass to that custom URL page.

I am using Tridion 2013 SP1.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What version of SDL Tridion are you using?

Comment: Tridion 2013 SP1

Comment: Edited tag to be 2013 - we don't use minor versions in Tridion version tags.

Comment: i am using window.dialogArguments.getFields(); mathod but it gives only current filed i.e Video ID and not able to get value of Video name and short Desc.

Answer (score 5):

There's a few good examples in the documentation on how to both read and modify values from a custom URL. Please read the chapter titled "[Manipulating field values from a Custom URL Resource](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-09AB9E31-DAA9-4032-813F-540DAF91812E)."

It seems to boil down to using `getFields` and `container` Javascript objects.

Comment: [Good edit](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/revisions/4963/2) from @jarnohenneman noting login required. I added a link. [See Meta for which links to use](http://meta.tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-to-reference-sdl-live-content-and-other-authenticated-sites).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is it possible to implement  with Tridion 2011 SP1 ?

Comment: Yes, Custom URLs are available in Tridion 2011 and even earlier, though the API and how to use the script have changed (since about 2011 SP1, where the docs say they were "deprecated"--but that just refers to how to call and use the script pop-up script).

Comment: I removed "login required."

Comment: The community also has examples on [TridionWorld](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/itemselector.aspx) and in [this post](http://tridionnut.blogspot.com/2013/02/custom-url-tridion.html). Since the question I also made [Color-](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/sdl-tridion-custom-url-color-picker) and [Coordinate-picker](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/custom-url-coordinate-picker) Custom URL examples.

Answer (score 0):

You should have you .NET application at tridionDir/web/ 
Add the following java script to layout of your application

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/WebUI/Core/Controls/Popup/PopupInit.js"></script>
```

In your application use the following java script code to get the other two fields-

```
var field = window.dialogArguments.container.getField('xml_fieldname').getValues();
var myvalue=field[0];
```