# setting a value in the text field of a component in SDL Tridion

Tags: 2011-sp1, component

How do I set the selected value in a text filed of a component on tridion front from a pop up popping with help of a custom url tagged to that text field ?

Comment: Have you read this http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4962/how-can-i-pass-values-in-a-custom-url

Comment: Thanks for joining Tridion Stack Exchange (TRex) and asking, Saxena. This is a good question but as getting fields with Custom URLs has been asked and answered before, I'm closing this so people can find information about Custom URLs in one location on TRex. I'll add a few more examples over there in case it helps. Feel free to ask additional questions as you set up your Custom URL. Sharing what you've tried, any errors, as well as expectation will help you get quality answers from the community.